# memcpy uint32_t and char* into char*

Tags: c, char, buffer, memcpy

this doesnt works for me:

```
char buff[11];
char* msg_ptr;
msg_ptr = buff;
uint8_t id; 
uint32_t msg_length;
char msg[] = "hallo";
id = 77;
msg_length = 5;

memcpy(buff, &id, sizeof(uint8_t));
memcpy(buff+1, &msg_length, sizeof(uint32_t));
strcpy(buff+5, msg);


printf("id :%d\n",*(uint8_t*)msg_ptr);
msg_ptr++;

printf("msg_length: %d\n", *msg_ptr);

msg_ptr++;
printf("msg: %s\n", msg_ptr);
```

Id and msg_lentgh are shown on konsole, but after that i get a segmentation fault.
I am new to C please be as detailied as possible.
Regards

Comment: This isn't your actual code (for a start, you have `msg_ptr` and `msg_prt`).  Please post your **actual** code.

Comment: You still have a typo in there.

Comment: Hi, typos are not the problem, they are easy to clear. I want to know my thinking error. I am new to stackoverflow and in the top left corner i noticed that someone commented that my buffer is to small. But it should not be: id(1 byte) + msg_length(4 byte) + msg(5 byte) = 10 byte.

Comment: @user1324258: Typos **are** a problem.  If you don't show your **actual** code, then we can't be sure that we're addressing the **actual** problem when we answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
msg_ptr = msg+1
```

That's your problem. You should do *msg_ptr++* to go to next position (which is *msg_len*). Instead you change the pointer to point the 'a' within the *msg* string.

2 more bugs in the code:

- You don't take into account the terminating '\0' of the string. You have 1 + 4 + 5 + 1, the last one being the terminating '\0'. Also, when working with strings use *strncpy*, which handles copying the string terminator. *memcpy* will copy exactly as much as you ask it to. You are corrupting your stack.
- On the last line you must print the string as a a number. Use %s.

Here's what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling) has to say about C strings and [stack overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) while you are at it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed reply. I updated my code. Now the segmentation fault is gone, but msg is null.

Comment: You didn't update the last msg_ptr correctly. It should be msg_ptr += sizeof(uint32_t) (aka 4).

Comment: When i do this, i get a segmentation fault again.

Comment: *buff* doesn't have the right size and you are not printing the string correctly (hint: dereferencing string pointer)

Comment: Okey size of buff should be 11. I do dereferencing the string pointer. Could you please tell me exactly whats wrong?

Comment: Ok it works. Why it doesnt works when using (int32_t)msg_ptr++ instaed of msg_ptr+=sizeof(uint32_t)

Comment: Because you must do ((int32_t *)msg_ptr)++. In your case you were converting the value to int32 and adding one. When converting it to a pointer to an int32, the compiler will do the magic of adding the sizeof(int32). If you had ((int16_t *)msg_ptr)++ it would to the magic of adding 2 to the value of the pointer.

Comment: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Typed_pointers_and_casting) should help explain better.

Comment: Sorry i made a scribal again, i should be (int32_t*)msg_ptr++ instead of (int32_t)msg_ptr++. So i have to put (int32_t*)msg_ptr into brackets before ++. That was the mistake. Thank you very much!!